# Passing array of class object using intent

Tags: android

How can I pass object array using intent from one activity to other and use the data object array in it?

I tried `Serializable` and `Parcelable`  but stuck with array passing due to nonconvertible types

code sample of part where i initialize object array and other is method to start activity

[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code as images is [discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Please [edit] your question with the actual code as text. Good formatting is optional.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, instead of passing an object array, send each value separately as an extra, considering that you are just trying to pass Strings.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataShow.class);
intent.putExtra("name", object.getString("name");
...
intent.putExtra("date_added", object.getString("date");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sampaio thanx for ur response but problem is i only know that i have three fields not the size of array i wrapped these fields in object and need to pass array of that object  so how many times i have to repeat these lines .